# android firebase Server Timestamp in CollectionReference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in an Android app I have the following:

```
notebookRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Registros");
notebookRef.add(new Lista(title, description, geoPoint, null));
Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
notebookRef.add(value);
```

it go mad because instead of generating a timestamp it write the following in the firebase:

[image]

the server should generate its own timestamp: [see here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#TIMESTAMP) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509091/using-servervalue-timestamp-in-my-android-app)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly using the [ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP) from Realtime Database instead of [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#serverTimestamp()) for Firestore.